# why my form data doesn't stored in database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

My app.js entire codes:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var port = 3000;


app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Server listening on port " + port);
});

var mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/node-demo", { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });

app.use("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

var nameSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String
});

var User = mongoose.model("User", nameSchema);

app.post("/addname", (req, res) => {

});

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post("/addname", (req, res) => {
    app.post("/addname", (req, res) => {
        var myData = new User(req.body.firstName, req.body.lastName);
        myData.save()
            .then(item => {
                res.send("item saved to database");
            })
            .catch(err => {
                res.status(400).send("unable to save to database");
            });
    })
});
```

This is my index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Intro to Node and MongoDB
    </title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Into to Node and MongoDB</h1>
    <form method="post" action="/addname">
        <label>Enter Your Name</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="Enter first name..." required>
        <input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="Enter last name..." required>
        <input type="submit" value="Add Name">
    </form>
</body>

<html>
```

After writing my code I open my mongod server than start mongo in other terminal then I run my app.js it worked properly it create server localhost:3000 then I went to my host I add my name in form and then submit, but it doesn't add to my database

Why this is not working?

My form data doesn't stored in my mongodb database. Please help me!

Comment: Can you share the front code?

Comment: yes i post in my question

Comment: Do you get any response after submitting?

Comment: Noooo.. it shows noting :(

Comment: Is the path correct? Are the app.js and html file in the same location?

Comment: yes it's in same folder

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not passing data correctly in the user model.

```
app.post("/addname", (req, res) => {
   // make sure your request object is getting the same properties
    var myData = new User(req.body.firstName, req.body.lastName);
    myData.save()
        .then(item => {
            res.send("item saved to database");
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(400).send("unable to save to database");
        });
});
```

As you updated the code for form, `lastName` is the fieldName. You should make the changes in the schema object too.

Also, Please check the request headers that comes in if it is of `Accept:multipart/form-data` then the bodyParser won't work instead you should use [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer).

Some useful body parsers that you might need to consider if needed.

- form-data: multer
- x-www-form-urlencoded: express.urlencoded()
- raw: express.raw()
- json: express.json()
- text: express.text()

Updated app.js file:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var port = 3000;


app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Server listening on port " + port);
});

var mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/node-demo", { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });

app.use("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

var nameSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String
});

var User = mongoose.model("User", nameSchema);

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post("/addname", (req, res) => {
        var myData = new User(req.body.firstName, req.body.lastName);
        myData.save()
            .then(item => {
                res.send("item saved to database");
            })
            .catch(err => {
                res.status(400).send("unable to save to database");
            });
});
```

Note: you have added two extra routes with same route handler, I have just removed it. Update this file in your project and run it.

Comment: So, the first thing is you need to check whether your form is actually submitting the data or not. If it is not you need to fix it first then apply these changes. If you are able to get the request in the route handler please check the values in the req.body.

Comment: no my form is not submiting the data. and there is no error in my app.js code

Comment: Also, I am checking the question code now, you have nested route handler. You should use only one.

Comment: I would request you to paste the whole app.js file instead in chunks. there is something in the node causing an issue.

Comment: okay i posted the whole app.js file.now check it and please find a solution

Comment: Please check now, updated the app.js file.

Comment: it doesn't work. After submiting it show nothing just reset my form

Comment: Have you checked the data coming in your handler?

Answer (score 0):

I think the body-parser library is deprecated on express 4 and later versions.

please use

app.use(express.json())

instead of body=parser.

not need to call any npm packages for parsing data from the form.

Comment: can  yoou elaborate

Answer (score 0):

i think i know what is wrong.

change `app.use("/"...` to `app.get("/"...`

bacause `use` handles all requests including POST. so when you send any request it sends the html file again and kills any other process.

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});
```

Comment: problem in loading after submiting

Comment: What do you get in the browser after submitting?

Comment: did you change `use` to `get`? Because i noticed now that in my answer i posted your original snippet. I edited it now.

Comment: i get nothing after submiting

Comment: Do you get a blank window? What do you get in the address bar?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the issue:

```
 var myData = new User(req.body.firstName, req.body.lastName);
```

you have to pass an object to new User

```
var myData = new User( { firstName:req.body.firstName, lastName:req.body.lastName } );
```

Comment: THere is showing error after doing this change. It is saying to put req,body.firstName instead of req.body.firstName